# Não consigo fazer tratamento de exceções no Controller em uma ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exceção, http-request, http-status

No código abaixo estou tentando fazer com que o status da requisição seja alterado quando não foi possível encontrar o ID do Project.

```
        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Project Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var project = _acess.GetProject(id);
                return project;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.InnerException.Message);
                
            }

        }
```

No entanto, me deparo com a seguinte mensagem de erro: CS0029: Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC.ObjectResult" em "SS_API.Model.Project"

Também preciso fazer o retorno das exceções de funções do tipo void, porém igualmente não sei como implementar um código que funcionasse. Segue código abaixo:

```
    public void Put([FromBody] Project project)
    {

        try
        {
            _acess.UpdateProject(project);
        }
        catch(DataException ex)
        {
          //Retorno do status do erro.
        }
      
    }
```

Peço encarecidamente para que alguém possa me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

O metodo GET não funciona pois na sua assinatura foi colocado que ele deveria devolver um Project (`public Project Get(int id)`) e não é o que acontece quando é lançada uma exceção, você pode alterar os metodos de retorno pra sempre devolverem um uma IHttpActionResult ou um ActionResult, algo como:

`public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)`
ou
`public ActionResult Get(int id)`

isso permite com que você devolva status ao inves de objetos, por exemplo, quando uma requisição foi bem sucedida você usa um

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<Project> Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var project = _acess.GetProject(id);
            return OK(project);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Sendo ok o status 200, quando um erro é retornado por parte de dados que o usuario informou ou algo relacionado, você retornaria um

```
return BadRequest("campo tal invalido");
```

O mesmo funcionaria para o seu metodo put, fazendo a operação que precisa ser feita e retornando um ok no final indicando que tudo que deveria ser feito, foi feito.

```
public ActionResult Put([FromBody] Project project)
{
    try
    {
        _acess.UpdateProject(project);
    }
    catch(DataException ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
     
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Eu não consigo utilizar o método Get sem declarar a função com assinatura do tipo Project, por essa razão só estou conseguindo utilizar ActionResult em funções que recebo Project como um parâmetro. Sua solução funcionou para mim na função Put, mas não na função Get. Teria alguma dica do que fazer?

Comment: Por quê não está conseguindo usar? pode postar a mensagem de erro? está usado o `return Ok(project)` ?

Comment: Desta maneira, meu Get não me retorna nada:
        public ActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var project = _acess.GetProject(id);
                
            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
               
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            return Ok(project);
        }

Comment: Deste outro modo:         public ActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var project = _acess.GetProject(id);
                return project;
            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
                
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            return Ok();
        }

Erro CS0029 Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "SS_API.Model.Project" em "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult"

Comment: @Tester Tente novamente o primeiro metodo informado só que ao inves de só `ActionResult`, utilize `ActionResult<Project>`, assim definimos explicitamente que ele ira retornar um project. Alias nada impede você de dar o return ok lá encima dentro do try onde estava sendo feito anteriormente, na verdade precisa ser assim, a variavel project só está definida dentro do block try, talvez seja por isso que nada está sendo retornado, o estranho é que você deveria estar tendo um erro de compilação com o código assim.

Comment: @Tester seria interessante saber também como está consumindo esse controller

Comment: @Tester atualizei a resposta pra conseguir visualizar melhor como deveria ficar o seu metodo GET

Comment: public ActionResult<Project> Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var project = _acess.GetProject(id);
                return project;
            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
                BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
Desta maneira consegui fazer funcionar, muito obrigado.

Comment: public ActionResult<bool> Delete(int id)
        {
            bool aux = false;

            _acess.GetProject(id);

            try
            {
                //Project project = _acess.GetProject(id);
                _acess.DeleteProject(id);
                _acess.Save();
                aux = true;


            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
                BadRequest(ex.Message);
                aux = false;
            }
            return aux;
        }
Pode me ajudar quanto ao que há de errado nesta? É possivel em bool?